# how to add paragraph on top of div content

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

How can I add multiple paragraph tag, newly tag on top within div container.

```html
<div id="pcontainer">
  <p>recently added on top every time on click event recently added paragarph on top</p>
  <p>added before recent</p>
</div>
```

I am using append but every time I click button it add to bottom I need it to added on top of all paragraph please help.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You may use [prepend](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/prepend) to add the paragraph at the top of the container:

```
// HTML: <div><p>Lorem ipsum</p></div>
$('div').prepend('<p>Bla bla bla');
```

**Update**: Regarding your comment about how to fade in the paragraph - use [fadeIn](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/fadeIn#speedcallback):

```
$("#pcontainer").prepend($('<p>This paragraph was added by jQuery.</p>').fadeIn('slow'));
```

A working demo: http://jsbin.com/uneso

Comment: you are alos right Moff both works, how i can add paragraph with fadein affect ?

Comment: Moff thanks, this just hiding the newly added p i need it to show with fade in affect how ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 51):

A more elegant way without jQuery:

```
var container = document.getElementById('pcontainer');
container.insertBefore(document.createElement("p"), container.firstChild);
```

This assumes there is already an element in the container btw.

Comment: This is easily the best solution without jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: An even better solution now is to use the [prepend()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend) method.

Answer (score 18):

An example for non jQuery-users:

```
document.getElementById('pcontainer').innerHTML = '<p>new paragraph</p>' + document.getElementById('pcontainer').innerHTML;
```

maybe not as short and nice though :)

Answer (score 3):

Try using [prepend](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation) instead of append.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way without jQuery:

```
function prependParagraphs()
{
     var choosenDiv = document.getElementById("pcontainer");
     for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
     {
         var newP = document.createElement("p");
         var text = document.createTextNode("new paragraph number: " + i);
         newP.appendChild(text);
         choosenDiv.insertBefore(newP, choosenDiv.firstChild);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specific to your HTML, it would be:

```
$("#pcontainer").prepend('<p>here's a new paragraph!</p>');
```

Comment: You're right. Just don't forget to escape your apostrophe there :)

Comment: how i can add fade in affect with this ?

Comment: You'd have to hide the paragraph first, then call the fadeIn function. So initially, it would be <p class="pHidden" style="display: none;">lkjsdlfkjs</p>, then you'd call $(".pHidden").fadeIn();

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little trick.
For example, first store your new html in a variable and append it in the container with the old content.

```
const container = document.getElementById("pcontainer")
container.innerHTML = `<p>new para you want to add</p> ${container.innerHTML}`
```

Answer (score 0):

A more updated solution without jquery is to use the [prepend()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend) method.

```js
function add() {
  let p = document.createElement('p')
  p.innerText = 'added before'
  document.getElementById('pcontainer').prepend(p)
}

button = document.getElementById('add')
button.addEventListener('click', add)
```

```html
<button id="add">add</button>

<div id="pcontainer">
  <p>begin</p>
</div>
```