# How to append the data at the top of the div using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have some content in the div and i need to append some data at the top of the previous content inside that div by moving the remaining content down after a jquery function call.

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add paragraph on top of div content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734041/how-to-add-paragraph-on-top-of-div-content) (this is the first hit if I [google for your exact question](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=How+to+append+the+data+at+the+top+of+the+div+using+jquery))

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
$("#mydiv").prepend(Data)
```

:)

That should do the trick :)

Answer (score 8):

Use the prepend command: http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

```
$('#yourDivId').prepend(yourContent);
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are using ajax call and want to set content at the top of div simply use
$('#divId').(AjaxContent);

This will work.