# Adding a <p> element inside a DIV with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need to add a message inside this  element using JavaScript.

```
<div id="messagePanel">
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript

```
    var calc = document.getElementById('form');

calc.addEventListener('submit', calculateAndPrintRisk);
var total;
var riskTotal;
var age;
var bmi;
var diet;
var diabetes;




function calculateRisk() {

  age = document.querySelector('input[name="age"]:checked').value;
  bmi = document.querySelector('input[name="bmi"]:checked').value;
  diabetes = document.querySelector('input[name="diabetes"]:checked').value;
  diet = document.querySelector('input[name="diet"]:checked').value;
  age = parseInt(age);
  bmi = parseInt(bmi);
  diabetes = parseInt(diabetes);
  diet = parseInt(diet);
  total = age + bmi + diabetes + diet;
  return total;

};


function calculateAndPrintRisk() {
  var riskTotal = calculateRisk();
  var message;
  var panel = document.getElementById("messagePanel");


    if (total <= 15) {
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("messagePanel");
    element.appendChild(para);


    } else if (total <= 25) {

          alert("medium");

   } else {

         alert("high");
     }

  }
```

This Div element is hidden, therefore, it would only appear when the message is displayed. The objective of the code, is to:
When the calculate button is pressed, the function calculateRisk() will calculate the value of each answer (age, bmi, diabetes, diet), sum them all together, and if the total is <= 15, a message has to be displayed in a box. This box needs to be hidden before the calculate button is pressed and only shown afterwards. When the box is shown, a message inside this box needs to be displayed and needs to stay there until I press calculate again.

```
#messagePanel{
width:600px;
height:150px;
border:1px solid black;
visibility: hidden;
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated as Im still a noob with javascript.
Thanks

Comment: There isn't actually a clear question here. Are you asking how to make the div visible? `panel.style.display = "block";` should fix that. You can google how to set CSS properties in JS quite easily

Comment: it would only appear when you also set `display` to something other than `none`.

Comment: You should add what is not working with your current solution.
I believe your problem is that for now the messagePanel will STILL be hidden when you add the p tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add paragraph on top of div content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734041/how-to-add-paragraph-on-top-of-div-content)

Comment: looking for this? `panel.style.display = "block";`

Comment: Maybe I was not very clear in my question. They DIV element is hidden thats why display is set to "none". What I need is to add the message "Your results show that you currently have a low risk of developing diabetes. However, it is important that youmaintain a healthy lifestyle in terms of diet and exercise. if the result of the function is <=15. If it is, the Div would be displayed with the message.

Comment: You're checking `total` but computing `riskTotal`

Comment: Set `panel.style.display = 'block';` at the end of function

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you need:

```
if (total <= 15) {
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("messagePanel");
    element.appendChild(para);
    }
```

Taken from: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_dom_elementcreate

As someone pointed in the comments, you will also need to remove the css class hidden from the messagePanel. You can do that in JavaScript as well.

Comment: This is very close to what I need. But for some reason the message "This is new" is displayed and is removed right after. I need it to stay there until the "calculate" button is pressed again. I will update my post to show the full code

Comment: Yes, please do.

Comment: I presume it's because of the form submit. Maybe try something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263414/dom-element-disappearing-immediately-after-update

Answer (score 0):

You can set CSS property for that div using JavaScript, try this

```
function calculateAndPrintRisk() {
  var riskTotal = calculateRisk();
  var message;
  var panel = document.getElementById("messagePanel");

  // hide this div by default
  panel.style.display = "block";

    if (total <= 15) {

        panel.innerHTML = "<p>Your results show that you currently have a low risk of developing diabetes. However, it is important that youmaintain a healthy lifestyle in terms of diet and exercise.</p>";

        // display the div
        panel.style.display = "block";

    } else if (total <= 25) {

          alert("medium");

   } else {

         alert("high");
     }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: none` hides the element and removes it from the flow. Any content inside it will also be invisible. You will need to remove that `display: none` from the div to make this work.

Optionally you can make the div 0 height, move it out of view, and/or set `visibility: hidden`, which hides the content, but doesn't remove the element from the flow, allowing parts of the content to be made visible again. 
When you do those things, you can still position the added paragraph to make it visible.